# AVPlayer can't load .mov file saved after re-running app via xcode

Tags: swift, avfoundation, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller, avplayeritem

I have this app in which the main purpose is to record video using AVFoundation, and then saving the outputfile delegate.

On first any normal run the app could properly record and save the video, and I could load the resulting outputfile URL into Avplayer I have on the next viewcontroller.

The AVPlayer would play just fine normally if the Xcode is not re-run. What I mean with rerunning is tapping into the Command+R again or clicking on the Play button on xcode to rebuild re-run.

What happens when I run the app again is that I could still see the files and list them via print, but when I'm trying to access the recorded file the app would no longer play the video. It would seem that the video wasn't loaded properly or anything even if it had already been working earlier. After this happens I could still go on record new ones and play the newly recorded ones, but not the old files.

The old files before rebuild of app would just look like this on AVPlayer[image: this is how it would look, I just took it from another stackoverflow which shows the same view but the problem is different]

Also the AVPlayer would successfully return .readyToPlay status on my observer.

I'm confused how should I go on fixing this one.

```
if let videoPreviewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "VideoPreviewController") as? VideoPreviewController {


                    let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/61E182ED-D490-4C7D-BAB7-C90D095C7E43/Documents/Thursday,%208%20June%202017%20at%201:47:51%20PM%20Philippine%20Standard%20Time.mov")
                    videoPreviewController.player = AVPlayer()
                    let playerItem = AVPlayerItem.init(url: url as URL)
                    videoPreviewController.player?.replaceCurrentItem(with: playerItem)

                    videoPreviewController.report = relationship
                    videoPreviewController.appointment = self.appointment
                    navigation.pushViewController(videoPreviewController, animated: true)
                }
```

Comment: Please show us the code you use to load the movie url.

Comment: @Mozahler i edited the post to have the code used to load the url.

Comment: OK. That was perfect. Unfortunately the paths change when an app is re-run, so you have to request the path before retrieving a file. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is this line:

```
  let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/61E182ED-D490-4C7D-BAB7-C90D095C7E43/Documents/Thursday,%208%20June%202017%20at%201:47:51%20PM%20Philippine%20Standard%20Time.mov")
```

That path will change every time your restart your app -- you can't hard code it.  You have to ask the OS for the path to your documents folder and append your filename to it.

```
let userDocumentsURL =  FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]

let fileName = "Thursday,%208%20June%202017%20at%201:47:51%20PM%20Philippine%20Standard%20Time.mov"

let movieURL = userDocumentsURL.appendingPathComponent(fileName)
```

And by the way, that's probably how you saved the file in the first place... get the path, append your filename and save it.

Comment: Actually I saved the full path of the file in database, I just modified code on top to shorten and make the point. I have no idea the path changes, but I'll modify my code in accordance to that idea. I'll let you know.

Comment: OK. You don't need to save the whole path to the DB. You can save the part below ..../Documents/ since some of the folders above Documents can change over time.

Comment: That was really helpful mate, I was able to make it work now that I was just saving the path after documents. Didn't know paths change until you told me. Thank you.